# Printer printing all text in single line

Tags: ios, swift, printing

i am printing text in textViewer but its not detecting line changes and prints all in one line. My code is:

```
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()!
    //The UIPrintInteractionController presents the user interface and manages the printing.

    let printinfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)!

    //The UIPrintinfo object contains information about the print job. This information is assigned to the printInfo property of the UIPrintInteractionController.


    printinfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
    printinfo.jobName = "Print Job"
    printController.printInfo = printinfo
    //The printing text can be formatted, here we define the insets for the printing page.

    let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: lblOutput.text)
    formatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 72, left: 72, bottom: 72, right: 72)
    printController.printFormatter = formatter
    printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
    //The user is presented the iPhone printing interface to select a printer and the number of copies.
```

What changes do i have to make in it. TextView contains multiple lines of text and it is important for me to insert lines when file is printed.

Comment: Old question, but: I guess that you have `\n` as "new lines" delimiter, while `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` expects HTML code as said in the doc. So to make it works, replace `\n` with `<br>` or check the other `UIPrintFormatter` available.